# Python dynamic string representing argument[i]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with Python and I tried searching for an answer here on SO but I can't seem to interpret any of the solutions supplied so far. I supply my python program with command line arguments (sys.argv) and the number of these argument may change from one run to another so I decided that it would be best to make an for loop that creates a new variable for each argument. The first argument is as we all know the script name, I dont want to include this, the second argument is a password string and i dont want this either, so it starts from the third argument. The print at the end is just to see if it works or not.

```
TempPersonNr = len(sys.argv)
TempPersonNr -= 2
VarPersonNr = ""

i = 1
for TempPersonNr in sys.argv[2:]:
  VarPersonNr[i] = sys.argv[i]
  print (VarPersonNr[i])
  i += 1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HIDDEN", line 31, in <module>
    VarPersonNr[i] = sys.argv[i]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I want the output to be something like this.

```
Argument 1 = A
Argument 2 = B
Argument 3 = C
```

If i supply the program with the following command line arguments I want it to create 3 variables with the value as the argument. For example.

```
VarPersonNr1  (with the value of argument 1) 
VarPersonNr2  (with the value of argument 2) 
VarPersonNr3  (with the value of argument 3)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: @Andreas I edited so the error is included

Comment: **Python string objects are immutable**

Comment: Okay but how can I go around this? It's a string so I can't really cast it to something else

Comment: This code wouldn't give that error, because you have not defined VarPersonNr - you'd get NameError instead. Presumably somewhere you've defined it as a string? Please show your *full* code, and what you want the output to be. (On the other hand, you've defined TempPersonNr three times, overriding the value each time; I don't know why you have done that.)

Comment: You don't need the first two lines (assignments to `TempPersonNr`) because you don't use the value. And where do you define `VarPersonNr`?

Comment: I added the VarPersonNr declaration, it was above this code segment

Comment: Yes but you haven't explained what you want this to *do*. As the error says, you can't assign to an element of a string. So what do you want the result to be?

Comment: I edited what I want the output to be

Comment: Maybe it should be a list. Create it with `VarPersonNr = []` and append to it with `VarPersonNr.append(sys.argv[i])`.

Comment: sys.argv is to my understanding already a list, could I use it directly maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, so you’ll have a list (you can name new variables in the way you described).
Also i think you don’t get well how for loops work...

```
TempPersonNr = len(sys.argv) - 2
VarPersonNr = []

for TempPerson in sys.argv[2:]:
    VarPersonNr.append(TempPerson)
    print (TempPerson)
```

Comment: But wouldn't append only give the variable it's value and not the actual name?

I need it to  both change the name (VarPersonNr+1) and then assign the value

Comment: So i think you need to think VarPersonNr as a list... anyway use lowercases for variables

Answer (score 0):

String objects are immutable you can't change it.
So when you are trying to assign the i th variable of the string to sys.argv[i] it gives an error.

EDIT:
As per your input and output you can directly assign the third value of sys.argv to your variable.
    varPersonNr3=sys.argv[i]

If you want to add rest of the arguments to that variable use:
    VarPersonNr3.append(sys.argv[i])

EDIT:
There are a couple of options for this:
1) You can use a dictionary to store the variable names as key and the sys.argv value as values:

```
d={}
TempPersonNr = len(sys.argv)
TempPersonNr -= 2
VarPersonNr = ""

i = 1
for TempPersonNr in sys.argv[2:]:
  key="VarPersonNr"+str(i)
  d[key]=sys.argv[i]
  i += 1
```

This will give you a dictionary {"VarPersonNr3":'C',"VarPersonNr4":'D'} and so on
2) You can add all the values to a list and fetch it from there.
3)  This is a very bad option and should not be used .. but still:

```
import sys
this = sys.modules[__name__]
i=1
for TempPersonNr in sys.argv[2:]:
   setattr(this, 'VarPersonNr%s' % i, sys.argv[i])
   i+=1
print(VarPersonNr3)
#this will give you the third value
```

Try using a dict or a list for this.

Comment: Yes I know this, but the problem is that I dont know beforehand how many arguments there will be, so I need the variable name to also follow i. aka variablename+i and value+i

Comment: One does not create variable variable names. There are data structures for this like `list` or `dict`.